# How to append different types of form inputs to formData()?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

My forms contains multiple input types (`file`, `number`, `text`, etc) while some of file inputs has `multiple` `attribute` and some doesn't. So the question is how can I append all these varies types to `formData()` without need of appending each input one-by-one ? Actually I'm thinking of a function to use it with all my forms.

Comment: The Mozilla documentation says that you can pass a form to the `FormData` constructor
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData ie
`new FormData(document.querySelector('#myForm'))`, and it will parse all the input in the form

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works with all types of input types (file [single & multiple], text, number , etc) :
`formData` is out object which contains our form data. for example of my empty object that is populating with data later:

```
formData : {
  first_name: null,
  last_name: null,
  image: null,
  thumbnails: [],
}
```

```
let formData = new FormData()
for(let key in this.formData) {
   if(typeof(this.formData[key]) === 'object') {
      if(this.formData[key].length) {
         for (let subKey in this.formData[key]) {
            formData.append(`${key}[]`, this.formData[key][subKey]);
         }
      } else {
         formData.append(key, this.formData[key]);
      }
   }
   else {
      formData.append(key, this.formData[key]);
   }
}
this.$axios.$post(url, formData, {
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }
}).then((response) => {
    // ...
}).catch((error) => {
   // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example

```
// data: {a:1,b:'2',c:[1,2,'3'],d: {a:1, b:3}, files:[]}
// data will be converted to FormData
const toFormData = data => {
  if (data instanceof FormData) return data
  const fd = new FormData()
  data &&
    Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
      const val = data[key]
      switch (typeof val) {
        case 'string':
          val && fd.append(key, val)
          break
        case 'number':
          ;(val || val === 0) && fd.append(key, val)
          break
        case 'boolean':
          fd.append(key, val)
          break
        case 'object':
          if (IsArray(val)) {
            val.length &&
              (typeof val[0] === 'object'
                ? fd.append(key, JSON.stringify(val))
                : fd.append(key, val))
          } else if (val instanceof File) {
            fd.append(key, val)
          } else if (val !== null) {
            fd.append(key, JSON.stringify(val))
          }
          break
      }
    })
  return fd
}
```